# Custom Notification in android

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

For my app I need different notification in different time.suppose i set a notification at time 11am ,12 am, 1pm and so one bt it is only giving the last one.i have used below code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MediaActivity.class);
    RQS = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, RQS, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

I have declared 
private int RQS_1;in MainActivity
How can i solve it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question title does not describe your problem, and the question is vague and poorly written. Please refer to the [How do I ask a good question? FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same notification id for all 3.  When you use the same id, you overwrite the old one with the new one.  If you want all 3 to stick around, use different ids.

Comment: would u explain in details please with example.i am not clear about this.

Comment: Read the docs.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int, android.app.Notification)